# Deselect the check boxes

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a form in JSP with three check boxes. When I select one check box, that should deselect other two check boxes. Like wise, for all the three check boxes. How to write the code for this one?

Comment: Wouldn't a `type='radio'` be a better fit for this?

Comment: No, that is the req they asked for..  :-(

Comment: @atlpeter, They need the solution. You are responsible for technical. Do the radio.

Comment: @JasonSperske Yes, you are correct. I did the same.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

wrap the checkboxes with a div container and give it an id, then assign onchange property to each checkbox like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="checkbox" value="0" onchange="setValues(this)"/><label>option 1</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" onchange="setValues(this)"/><label>option 2</label><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" onchange="setValues(this)"/><label>option 3</label><br/>
</div>
```

Then use this code:

```
function setValues(elm){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('checkbox');
    for(var i=0; i< checkboxes.length; i++)
    {
      checkboxes[i].checked = (checkboxes[i] === elm) ? true: false;
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/FJ2PD/)